# How to take the logical and of a list of boolean functions in python

Tags: python

Say I have a list of functions `li = [fun1, fun2, ..., funk]` that take one argument and return a boolean. I'd like to compose them into a single function that returns the logical and of the return values of each of the `fun`'s when evaluated at its argument. (in other words I'd like to have `fun(x) = fun1(x) and fun2(x) and ... and funk(x)`.)

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to create the composite function

```
def func(x, lst):

    #lst is the list of functions and x is used as an argument for functions
    return all(fun(x) for fun in lst)
```

And then call it as

```
func(x,[fun1, fun2, fun3,...., funk])
```

If a lambda function is needed, you can do the following, however it is against [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.

```
func = lambda x:all(fun(x) for fun in lst)
```

And call it as

```
func(x)
```

Comment: Assigning a lambda to a name is against PEP8 style guidelines

Comment: aah okay, so what will be the correct way to do it @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess to just use a def ? Anyways, I have added the relevant statement to the answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for your comment, and Devesh for your answer

Comment: Thanks @gen as I mentioned in the answer, and juanpa also said, using `def` is better instead of the lambda construct

Answer (score 0):

[all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) will do it

```
all(func(x) for func in li)
```

Comment: so I guess this should be a lambda, so that you have a function... after all x is a variable?

Comment: Lambda or a normal function, both are fin but if just want for the single time usage then you can do `is_true = all(func(x) for func in li)`

Comment: `all(func(x) for func in li)` is not a function, unless I misunderstood something